# Custom data annotation with mutual exclusion does not validate empty fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am working on a project in ASP.Net MVC4 with Visual Studio 2010. I have a requirement to implement a custom data annotation. My requirement is like below

1) There are two fields IP Address and Host Name. User can enter either of them. But not both

2) It needs to be validated accordingly and when user types into one of them, other one needs to cleared automatically.

3) I also need to validate that both should not empty

Based on the above requirements, I cameup with two custom attributes like as below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    public class IPAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {

        #region Propertie(s)
        /// <summary>
        /// Other dependent properties for validation
        /// </summary>
        public string CommaSeperatedProperties
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor(s)
        /// <summary>
        /// Parameterized constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="otherProperties">Other properties required for validation</param>
        public IPAddressAttribute(string otherProperties): base(defaultErrorMessage)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(otherProperties))
            {
                this.CommaSeperatedProperties = otherProperties;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Method(s)

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>
                    GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            return new[] { new IPAddressValidationRule
            (FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
            CommaSeperatedProperties.Split(new char[]{','})) };
        }
        #endregion

        #region Protected Method(s)
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                    ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
           // Validation logic goes here
        }
        #endregion

        #region Field(s)
        private const string defaultErrorMessage = "{0} is invalid";
        #endregion
    }

/// <summary>
    /// Implements a custom validation attribute for Host name
    /// </summary>
    public class HostNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {

        #region Propertie(s)
        /// <summary>
        /// Other dependent properties for validation
        /// </summary>
        public string CommaSeperatedProperties
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor(s)
        /// <summary>
        /// Parameterized constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="otherProperties">Other properties required for validation</param>
        public HostNameAttribute(string otherProperties) : base(defaultErrorMessage)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(otherProperties))
            {
                this.CommaSeperatedProperties = otherProperties;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Method(s)

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule>
                    GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            return new[] { new HostNameValidationRule
            (FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName), 
            CommaSeperatedProperties.Split(new char[]{','})) };
        }
        #endregion

        #region Protected Method(s)

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                    ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            // Validation goes here
        }
        #endregion

        #region Field(s)
        private const string defaultErrorMessage = "{0} is invalid";
        #endregion
    }
```

My javascript is like below

```
// Register method for the client side validation of IP Address
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("ipaddress", ['id', 'hostname'],
function (options) {
    var params = {
        id: options.params.id,
        hostname: options.params.hostname
    };
    options.rules['ipaddress'] = params;
    options.messages['ipaddress'] = options.message;
});

// Register method for the client side validation of Host name
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("hostname", ['id', 'ipaddress'],
function (options) {
    var params = {
        id: options.params.id,
        ipaddress: options.params.ipaddress
    };
    options.rules['hostname'] = params;
    options.messages['hostname'] = options.message;
});


// jquery validate function to validate an IP address
$.validator.addMethod("ipaddress", function (value, element, params) {
    var result = true;
    if (value != "") {
        result = validateIPAddress(value);
        // Clear the host name field, since they are mutually exclusive
        var tempInd = element.id.search("IPAddress");
        var hostNameCtrlID = element.id.substring(0, tempInd) + params.hostname;
        if ($("#" + hostNameCtrlID).val() != "") {
            $("#" + hostNameCtrlID).val("");
            // trigger the validation in Host name field
            //$("#remDevForm").valid();
            if (result) {
                result = $("#myForm").validate().element($("#" + hostNameCtrlID));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // if both are empty, return false
        var tempInd = element.id.search("IPAddress");
        var hostNameCtrlID = element.id.substring(0, tempInd) + params.hostname;
        if ($("#" + hostNameCtrlID).val() == "") {
            result = false;
            $.validator.messages.ipaddress = "Please enter either Hostname or IP Address";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
);

// jquery validate function to validate Host name
$.validator.addMethod("hostname", function (value, element, params) {
    var result = true;
    if (value != "") {
        var result = validateHostName(value);
        // Clear the IP Address field, since they are mutually exclusive
        var tempInd = element.id.search("HostName");
        var ipAddressCtrlID = element.id.substring(0, tempInd) + params.ipaddress;
        if ($("#" + ipAddressCtrlID).val() != "") {
            $("#" + ipAddressCtrlID).val("");
            // trigger the validation in IP Address field
            //$("#myForm").valid();
            if (result) {
                result = $("#myForm").validate().element($("#" + ipAddressCtrlID));
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // if both are empty, return false
        var tempInd = element.id.search("HostName");
        var ipAddressCtrlID = element.id.substring(0, tempInd) + params.ipaddress;
        if ($("#" + ipAddressCtrlID).val() == "") {
            result = false;
            $.validator.messages.hostname = "Please enter either Hostname or IP Address";
        }
    }
    return result;
});
```

The validation works well individually

I am facing below issues in client side validation.

1) Validation is not triggered when field is becoming empty. Is this a bug? Please note that I can not use required, since only of them is mandatory. If I enter some value, it is triggering

2) Not able to get the custom messages as I put above in java script. Instead of this, I am always getting default error message.

I know that it is a lengthy code and sorry for the same. Can anyone comment what may be happening wrong?